# How to listen to a socket and connect to a different socket(same ip address but different port number) in a same c program

Tags: c, sockets

Hi I am figuring out a way to listen to a socket and connect to a different socket(on same ip but different port number) simultaneously in the same program.when I listen to a socket then it keeps blocking until it receives some message so I am not able to listen and connect simultaneously.
I actually need to simulate exchange of LSP packets between different routers. So I am writing a program to simulate a router so as to run it n(number of routers)times.

Could anyone please share on how to proceed ??

Comment: You can multi thread or use `poll`.

Comment: So your problem is that your listening socket blocks when a client connects, but you want to be able to allow other clients to connect while another client is currently connected?

Comment: You can use select() and non-blocking sockets.  http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html

Comment: @Koralarts No my problem is when I use accept It will wait for incoming connections(I want to connect to a different socket while receiving incoming connections from others at the same time). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, one of these might help.

**Multi-thread or Multi-process**

Basically, when you receive a client you can process a client separately in a separate thread or in a new process. You will be able to receive incoming connections and connect to new clients from other sources while processing the ones who are already connected.

Pseudo Code:

```
main() {
  while(1) {
    accept client
    /* 
    After the fork or creation of the new thread, the loop goes back to 
    accepting clients while connected clients are being processed.
    */
    fork or create new thread passing and client socket to it
  }
}

processClient() {
  do whatever you need to do...
}
```

**Select**

Select is another good way of doing non-blocking sockets. Select basically waits for data to come (ie. data, new client requests) to the server and processes them one-by-one. The server will not block on accept as it will wait until it receives something before processing it.

Psuedo Code:

```
main() {
  while(1) {
     wait on select
     if new client {
       accept it
     }
     for client in clients {
       if client has data {
         process it
       }
     }
  }
}
```

**ePoll (if you're in Linux)**

ePoll is similar to Select only it can handle WAY more clients and it's a lot sexier.

Here's a repo that has each of those. My code isn't perfect here as it was a project that I did while in school.

https://github.com/koralarts/ServerBenchmarking